# About IE Event Processing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am writing because I have a question during the development.
Drag and drop with the same sauce
Chromium and edge work normally, but not in ie.
The interesting thing is that there are three connection routes with A server, B server, and C server that appear to be the same source, but only one path (B server URL) does not work
I wonder if there's a reason for this.
I don't know if this is a server issue or a source issue...
I ask for your advice.

Comment: Why would you use a dead browser?

Comment: I don't want to use it either, but the company said it would be used, and the ie mode is possible at the edge, so we are proceeding like that.

Comment: maybe you should rewrite all your code in jQuery 2 (IE'latest). Estimate time & rewritting costs, lost's functionalities list, risks to have a result. The main issue here is about realizing how many problems there are to use old technology like IE and the benefits of leaving it in its grave. There is also a possibility that the IEs used have a Trojan (or in future), grafted onto their JS interpreter who damage the Drag and drop functionalities. In short, believing that we can continue to use IE is like wanting peace in the world at a Miss (or Mr. Muscle) contest.

Comment: Does this issue occur in IE mode or IE?